# SQL: Is there a possibility to filter on two values with a chronological CASE attached?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset based on scanningdata (warehouse). My goal is to analyse the 'movements'. For example BARCODE UNLOAD , after this the shipment will receive a ASSIGN LOCATION scan. For this to be accurate I need to filter on `SCAN_EVENT_TYPE + SCAN_LOCATION`. So the movement from V-14 to V-02 is not planned `(=1 movement to many) but the movement from V-02 -> V-02` is a scan from the round they make every morning in the warehouse to check how many pieces are still on the floor (=not a extra movement)

https://imgshare.io/image/test.nr6iO

**Question**How can I lookup through this query based on those two values and use the scan_date as a check on the flow.

Also for me to be completely 100% accurate I need to use the SCAN_DATE
For Example:

```
FLOW for SHIPMENT A
UNLOAD BARCODE
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-14 08:00
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:15
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-20 08:30
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:45
```

In this case I want to see both V-02 scan. Because now V-20 came in between.

```
FLOW for SHIPMENT B
UNLOAD BARCODE
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-14 08:00
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:15
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:45
```

In this example I only want to see 1 V-02 scan (1 scan is from the morning round they make in the warehouse)

I've tried inline selects, MIN, MAX values and more stuff. But I can't find a grip on a solid solution

```
select 
scal.BARCODE
, scal.SCAN_EVENT_TYPE
, scal.SCAN_DATE
, scal.SCAN_LOCATION
, scal.SCAN_ZONE
, scal.DOCK
, scal.H_ID_ORDER
, scal.ID_GOODS
, scal.SOURCE
from dwh.S_ORD_SCAN_LOCATIONS scal
where scal.BARCODE in
(
select 
scal1.BARCODE
from dwh.S_ORD_SCAN_LOCATIONS scal1
where scal1.SCAN_EVENT_TYPE in ('ASSIGN LOCATION', 'BARCODE LOAD', 'BARCODE UNLOAD')
and year(scal1.scan_date) = 2018
group by scal1.BARCODE,  scal1.SCAN_EVENT_TYPE, scal1.ID_GOODS
having count(scal1.BARCODE) > 2)

order by 1,2,6
```

I only want to see barcodes who received more than 2 scans grouped by barcode, scan_event_type and id_goods

**Expected results**
  FLOW for SHIPMENT A

```
UNLOAD BARCODE 
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-14 08:00
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:15
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-20 08:30
ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:45
```

I expect to see 3 'movements' in this case. From V-14 to V-02, From V-02 to V-20, From V-20 to V-02

```
  FLOW for SHIPMENT B
    UNLOAD BARCODE
    ASSIGN LOCATION = V-14 08:00
    ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:15
    ASSIGN LOCATION = V-02 08:45
```

I expect to see 1 result here. From V-14 to V-02 (and the second V-02 is cancelled)

Comment: please post your expected ouput.

Comment: Format the question well!

Comment: You could use something like ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BARCODE, ScanEventType, Location ORDER BY Date) AS RN using a CTE and only select rows with a RN = 1